# Search in file, but not into subdirectories

Tags: vim

I am using the `:vim COMPANY_ID ~/Projects/creditdutile/loanrabbit/* | cw` command to look for the word `COMPANY_ID` in the `loanrabbit` directory. However, that command look for just for file I guess, not in subdirectories. How could I make a global research with that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're invoking that command from inside Vim.  You can use `**` to search a directory tree.  i.e.

```
:vimgrep COMPANY_ID ~/Projects/creditdutile/loanrabbit/** | cw
```

See `:h starstar-wildcard` for the full documentation on `**`.  Also note that you can use `**` as part of a path.  For example I often search some templates with:

```
:vimgrep h1 temp**/*.html
```

and it matches both `templates/foo.html` and `temp/extra/templates/bar.html`

---

Shameless marketing: we have a [Vi & Vim stack exchange community](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this site doesn't point every single vim question at the vim site.

Comment: @DrEval - There are some good old Vim questions here and on SU too.  And many more on SO.  Most of them from before the creation of vi.SE .  We are struggling a little with not enough marketing of the site on vi.SE :) .  Directing Vim users to vi.SE must be the solution to that.

Comment: Your answer is good, but has got certain limit. In `loanrabbit`, I have files and subdirectories. `:vimgrep COMPANY_ID ~/Projects/creditdutile/loanrabbit/** | cw` looked inside subdirectories, but not inside files from `loanrabbit`. Could you tell me how could I pass through all files and subdirectories inside `loanrabbit`?

Comment: @J.Doe - I'm pretty confident that the starstar does match both files and directories in that scenario.  Yet, If i'm not mistaken, there was a bug with the ending `/` at some point.  You may be using that version (i'm using v8.0.329).  In any case, `loanrabbit**` instead of `loanrabbit/**` should go around that issue (may cause issues if you have another directory named, e.g. `loanrabbit.old` though).

Answer (score 1):

I am having some trouble understanding the question, but `grep -nr "COMPANY_ID" ~/Projects/creditdutile/loanrabbit/` should be a nice way of searching for the word `COMPANY_ID` in all files in that directory and any sub-directories.

If you are trying to do this from vim then you almost had it `:vimgrep ~/Projects/creditdutile/loanrabbit/** | cw`should do it. The asterisks allow you to search throughout the directory.

Answer (score 0):

use the grep command

```
grep -r "COMPANY_ID" ~/Projects/creditdutile/loanrabbit/
```

Comment: Sorry, but according to me, `grep` is the low range of `:vim`. This is not my question.